# Pass parameter to routes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

On main.dart I have StatelessWidget and StatefulWidget.

In StatefulWidget in variable myUsername set USERNAME from sharedPreferences.

How pass USERNAME from StatefulWidget  to StatelessWidget

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => MyHomePage(title: 'Home'),
        '/myUser':(context) => MyUser(paramUser: "set here username from StatefulWidget"  )
      },
      title: 'app',
    );
  }
}
```

Or any better solutin?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation is perform only one page to another page. So if you want to pass the data from one to another then create Constructor for any particular page then pass the data toward them.

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isMyPost;
  final String postId;

  const UserPage({Key? key, required this.postId, this.isMyPost = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ UserPage State createState() => _ UserPage State();
}

class _ UserPage State extends State< UserPage > {

//Rest of Code
}
```

then navigate like that:

```
Navigator.push(context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => Preview(
    postId:provider.searchPost[index].postId,
                                    )));
```